# "measure_data" column migration error (NPE) when upgrading from SonarQube 4.3.2 to 4.4

Tags: sonarqube

Hi

When migrating from Sonar 4.3.2 to 4.4 database update fails with the following exception:

```
2014.08.28 13:16:31 INFO [DbMigration] == MergeMeasureDataIntoProjectMeasures: migrating ============================
2014.08.28 13:16:31 INFO [DbMigration] – add_column(:project_measures, "measure_data", :binary, {:null=>true})
2014.08.28 13:28:59 INFO [DbMigration] -> 747.4790s
2014.08.28 13:28:59 INFO [DbMigration] -> 10014240 rows
2014.08.28 13:29:02 INFO [o.s.s.d.m.MassUpdater] 0 rows have been updated
2014.08.28 13:29:02 ERROR [o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v44.MeasureDataMigration
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException
2014.08.28 13:29:02 ERROR [o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to upgrade database
An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:
Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.server.db.migrations.v44.MeasureDataMigration
org.sonar.server.db.migrations.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(DatabaseMigrator.java:100
```

)

When trying to perform migration through intermediate 4.3.3 then 4.3.2 -> 4.3.3 migration succeeds and 4.3.3 -> 4.4 migration fails with the same exception.

Have you seen such problem? What would you advise to do?

We have found [SONAR-5249](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5249) Merge measure_data and project_measure tables (but it seems to be fixed in 4.4. No connected issues is found in 4.4.+ scope)

P.s. Copying this issue from the sonar-user mailing list. Looks like this problem does not get any traction there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `measure_data` mapping table contained one entry with `measure_id` equal to `NULL`. Use

```
SELECT * FROM measure_data WHERE measure_id IS NULL
```

to check whether that is the case. Erroneous entries may be deleted using

```
DELETE FROM measure_data WHERE id=${ERRONEOUS_MEASURE_DATA_ID}
```